# Для чего нужны атрибуты маршрутизации?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

В [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) приложении методам в контроллере можно указать так называемые атрибуты маршрутизации: `[Route]` & `[RoutePrefix]`.

Помогите разобраться для каких целей принято использовать данный функционал.

---

На сколько я смог понять при помощи данных *атрибутов* можно *построить* более удобночитаемые `url`:

```
public ActionResult GetDetailUserInfo(int userId){}
```

при отсутствии атрибутов `url` адрес будет выглядеть как:

***ИмяКонтроллера/GetDetailUserInfo?userId=5***

если же к методу добавить атрибут маршрутизации `[Route("{userId}/Details")]`

то тогда `url` будет выглядеть так:

***ИмяКонтроллера/5/Details***

есть ли какие то другие случаи когда нужно использовать данные атрибуты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В asp.net mvc есть два варианта задания маршрутов. Оба можно настроить одинаково, но есть принципиальное отличие.

Первый вариант (вы декларируете маршруты в конфигурации, в одном месте):

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: “ProductPage”,
   url: “{productId}/{productTitle}”,
   defaults: new { controller = “Products”, action = “Show” },
   constraints: new { productId = “\\d+” }
);
```

И новый более удобный и гибкий способ (рекомендуемый), основанный на атрибутах контролёра. Он даёт возможность децентрализовать настройку маршрутов и более интуитивно понятен.

В конфиге:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

В контролёре:

```
public class BooksController : Controller
{
   // eg: /books
   // eg: /books/1430210079
   [Route(“books/{isbn?}”)]
   public ActionResult View(string isbn)
   {
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(isbn))
       {
           return View(“OneBook”, GetBook(isbn));
       }
       return View(“AllBooks”, GetBooks());
    }

    // eg: /books/lang
    // eg: /books/lang/en
    // eg: /books/lang/he
    [Route(“books/lang/{lang=en}”)]
    public ActionResult ViewByLanguage(string lang)
    {
       return View(“OneBook”, GetBooksByLanguage(lang));
    }
}
```

Подробнее можно прочитать [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/).